# How to select column values in a data frame using column values of other data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose that you create the next python pandas data frames:

```
In[1]: print df1.to_string()
    ID value
0   1     a
1   2     b
2   3     c
3   4     d


In[2]: print df2.to_string()
      Id_a  
0     1            
1     4            
2     2            
3     3            
4     4            
5     2
```

How can I update **df2**, such that will look like:

```
In[2]: print df2.to_string()
      Id_a  value 
0     1     a       
1     4     d       
2     2     b       
3     3     c       
4     4     d       
5     2     b
```

In other words, I would like to add an extra column based in the values of **df1**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2,3,4], "value": ["a","b","c","d"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Id_a": [1,4,2,3,4,2]})

merged_df = pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on="Id_a", right_on="ID")
print merged_df
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pd.merge(df1.rename(columns={'ID':'Id_a'}),df2,on='Id_a')
```