# fill a column in my data frame conditional on other column, with values from third column

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

Warning: this question seems so easy that I as a beginner probably did not manage to find the right solution among the more complex topics on SO (looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185450/r-fill-column-with-values-from-any-other-columns), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125098/replace-column-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-other-columns), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437138/how-to-select-column-values-in-a-data-frame-using-column-values-of-other-data-fr) and at more places)

I would like to fill a column in my dataframe, based on another column, and using as input further columns.
This is much clearer with an example:

```
  Version1 Version2 Version3 Version4 Presented_version Color
1     blue      red    green   yellow                 1    NA
2      red     blue   yellow    green                 4    NA
3   yellow    green      red     blue                 3    NA
```

I would like to fill the column "**Color**" with the value of either Version1/Version2/Version3/Version 4. The column **Presented_version** tells me which of these four values is needed.
For example, in row 1, Presented_version is 1, so the value needed is in "Version1" ("blue"). Color in row 1 should be blue.

Could someone show me a way to do this without looping over the dataframe using lots of "if" statements?

```r
structure(list(Version1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("blue", "red", 
"yellow"), class = "factor"), Version2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("blue", "green", "red"), class = "factor"), Version3 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("green", "red", "yellow"), class = "factor"), 
    Version4 = structure(3:1, .Label = c("blue", "green", "yellow"
    ), class = "factor"), Presented_version = c(1L, 4L, 3L), 
    Color = c(NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

=======================
EDITED!

I simplified the example to explain my question but the example above differs in several ways from my actual dataset, and the solutions therefore make assumptions which my data do not actually meet.
Here is a more accurate representation of the data.frame. In particular, there is no fixed match between Presented_version and the content of the Version1...Version 4 columns (that differs depending on an extra column, which I called Painter now), and Version1 to Version4 are not necessarily in column 1 to 4 in my dataset.

```
  FillerColumn Painter Version1 Version2 Version3 Version4 Version_presented Color FillerColumn.1
1           77       A     blue      red    green   yellow                 1    NA             77
2           77       B      red     blue   yellow    green                 4    NA             77
3           77       C   yellow    green      red     blue                 3    NA             77
4           77       D      red     blue   yellow    green                 1    NA             77
```

```
structure(list(FillerColumn = c(77L, 77L, 77L, 77L), Painter = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Version1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("blue", "red", "yellow"), class = "factor"), 
    Version2 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("blue", 
    "green", "red"), class = "factor"), Version3 = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("green", "red", "yellow"), class = "factor"), 
    Version4 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("blue", 
    "green", "yellow"), class = "factor"), Version_presented = c(1L, 
    4L, 3L, 1L), Color = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), FillerColumn.1 = c(77L, 
    77L, 77L, 77L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `mapply`

```
cols <- grep("^Version", names(df))
df$Color <- unlist(mapply(function(x, y) df[x, cols][y], 
                   1:nrow(df),df$Presented_version))

df
#  Version1 Version2 Version3 Version4 Presented_version Color
#1     blue      red    green   yellow                 1  blue
#2      red     blue   yellow    green                 4 green
#3   yellow    green      red     blue                 3   red
```

---

And with `apply`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) x[cols][as.numeric(x["Presented_version"])])
#[1] "blue"  "green" "red"
```

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(df[x, cols], y) : undefined columns selected 

The actual names of the columns are different in the original dataframe, they are:Story1 Story2 Story3 Story4  StoryPresented.

(Apologies, I thought I was wrong and deleted the comment, but there is indeed an error if I try to run the code on my actual dataset.)

Comment: @Kastany in that case you need `cols <- grep("Story\\d+", names(df))` since you don't want to consider `StoryPresented` column.

Comment: Ah, I'm so sorry, I think the example was too simplified. My dataframe contains further columns in addition to Story1/2/3/4, and I now realize that grep is about the column index. So probably it does not work because I get 
> cols
[1] 2 3 4 5 
and that does not match with StoryPresented. Thanks for the help! 

I dont want to take up so much of your time, I'll try to find a workaround by working with a subset of the dataset and then merging.

Comment: Thank you, used the solution with the following changes to account for na's in the data and allow for flexible indices (I had some help with this):
cols <- mapply(
  function(x) match(x, names(df)),
  c("Story1", "Story2", "Story3", "Story4")
)

df$Color <- unlist(
  mapply(
    function(x, y) if(is.na(y)) return(NA) else return(df[x, cols][y]), 
    1:nrow(df),
    df$StoryVersion))

Answer (score 4):

We can use a vectorized option with `row/column` indexing to extract the values instead of any loop

```
df1$color <- df1[1:4][cbind(1:nrow(df1), df1$Presented_version)]
df1$color
#[1] "blue"  "green" "red"
```

#### Benchmarks

```
dfN <- df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 1e6),]


system.time({
   dfN[1:4][cbind(1:nrow(dfN), dfN$Presented_version)]

 })
# user  system elapsed 
#   1.216   0.110   1.321


system.time({
 cols <- grep("^Version", names(dfN))
 unlist(mapply(function(x, y) dfN[x, cols][y], 
                    1:nrow(dfN),dfN$Presented_version))

 })
#  user  system elapsed 
# 319.907   1.644 322.418
```

Now, let's see the other option with `apply`

```
system.time({
  apply(dfN, 1, function(x) x[cols][as.numeric(x["Presented_version"])])
 }) 
#  user  system elapsed 
# 14.240   0.365  14.550
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `[1:4]` in `df1[1:4]`? It works without that too.

Comment: @nsinghs I am only selecting the 'Versions' columns instead of the whole dataset.  With big data, it could make some difference.  Also, if there are mixed column types, it could be affect the output as well

Comment: Definitely, the row/column indexing would be faster but any idea why there is such a huge difference in `apply` vs `mapply` solution? I expected `apply` to be even slower. Is it just a notion that `apply` is slower and is not true in every case ?

Comment: @akrun, I see.  That makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: Could be that in each loop, the data.frame is called and then subset the row/column

Comment: Thank you for the help! Works! 
I am not sure I understand the code, so just to be save: Does this solution assume that the "Version"columns are sorted and complete in order from 1 to 4? So if I had instead columns Version3 Version1 Version5, this would not work, right?

Comment: @Kastany  It is based on the column index in "Presented_version" assuking that the 'Version' columns are in the same order you wanted.  Lets say you arranged columns as 'Version1" "Version2", "Version3", "Version4" and your first row for 'Presented_version" is 3, it gets the value in 'Version3".  If the columns are arranged as "Version3", "Version2", "Version1", "Version4", it gets value of "Version1" or else have to do a change in the column order

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I like to mess with the data set. Try a data.table `melt` approach

```
df <- setDT(df)

df1 <- melt.data.table(df,
                       id.vars = c('Presented_version'),
                       measure.vars = patterns('Version'),
                       value.name = 'Color',
                       variable.name = 'Version')[
  , version1 := str_extract(Version, '\\d+')][
    Presented_version == version1][
      version1 := NULL]
```

resulting in

```
   Presented_version  Version Color 
1:                 1 Version1  blue        
2:                 3 Version3   red        
3:                 4 Version4 green
```

And, if you want the information in the same original structure

```
merge(df, 
      df1[, .(Presented_version, Color)],
      by = 'Presented_version')

   Presented_version Version1 Version2 Version3 Version4 Color
1:                 1     blue      red    green   yellow  blue
2:                 3   yellow    green      red     blue   red
3:                 4      red     blue   yellow    green green
```

Comment: thank you, this is the solution that I ended up using! I had to tweak it to include further id.vars because the actual dataframe is a bit more complex, but it does what I need and I understand the solution :)